# How do Electric and magnetic fields generate each other (mathematically)?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Regarding electromagnetism, a changing magnetic flux$(\phi_B)$ produces emf by-$$EMF= -\frac{d \phi_B}{dt}\tag1$$
This emf creates a current which again creates a magnetic field given by-(bio-savart law) $$dB= \frac{kI×dl}{r^2}\space\space\space\space\space\space (2)$$ assume appropriate constants and vectors.

But if this emf is such that, it is also changing with time then it creates a time varying current I(t) which will then produce a time varying magnetic field by (2) (maybe)   and the process is again back  to (1) i.e we have a changing magnetic flux. This is obviously wrong and shouldn't happen as it may become endless loop creating $\infty$ E and B fields.

I am highly unsure about everything I have written, as I am not confident in this topic but please explain my misunderstanding here. Also I am fully aware of the four Maxwell equations and their basic meaning. I know this topic can get too complicated as it uses tensors and such so keep math (if any) moderate graduation level

Comment: you may find  these answers useful https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/557499/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/458579/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Linked differential equations *may* reinforce one another leading to unbounded exponential growth - but they do not have to.

For example, the linked equations

$\displaystyle y = \frac {dx}{dt}
\\ \displaystyle x = \frac {dy}{dt}$

with initial conditions $x(0)=y(0)=1$ have solution

$x = e^t
\\ y = e^t$

which is unbounded as $t \rightarrow \infty$. But if we introduce a negative sign as follows:

$\displaystyle y = -\frac {dx}{dt}
\\ \displaystyle x = \frac {dy}{dt}$

with the same initial conditions $x(0)=y(0)=1$ then the solution is

$x = \cos(t) - \sin(t)
\\y = \cos(t) + \sin(t)$

which is bounded for all $t$.

The interaction between electric and magnetic fields is like the latter case (although more complicated since we have spatial dimensions to consider as well).

Comment: So basically for 2 linked differentials to not have a "unbounded exponential growth" they must have a relation similar to "an increase in 1st should induce a decrease in the 2nd" (obviously the above statement is written in the simplest form and sense). So by thinking i realised that when we have a increasing magnetic flux or field this field reduces the electric filed in the region but since at t=0 electric field is '0' thus magnetic field reduces the field below 0 thus creating a electric field.(this is what people mean when they say magnetic field creates E field but actually the B field...

Comment: just wanted to reduce E... lol is it really how it works?

Comment: @AmitRai This answer is not relevant for this question, which is about the Maxwell-Faraday law of induction. The answer is nevertheless relevant to the Maxwell-Ampère law.

Answer (score 4):

From a spatial point of view, it very much looks like a changing electric field generates a changing magnetic field. And vice-versa. But this raises the problem of causality and locality.

Its general taken in physics the cause and effect are local. Hence, if we wave an electron, the changing electric field will generate a changing magnetic field. But then by locality, you can equally say, after the initial cause, that a changing magnetic field generates the changing electric field. Thus what causes which becomes ambiguous. Of course one could posit instead Liebniz pre-established harmony. (Actually, this view, which sounds incredible begins to make sense when there is no time, for then there can be no temporal cause amd effect).

This puzzle is resolved once we move into a spacetime view. Then the electric and magnetic spatial wave are combined into a single spacetime EM field strength. It is this that varies. And its only when we choose a split of spacetime into space and time that we obtain the electric and magnetic fields.

Comment: Your last sentence is unfinished.

Answer (score 4):

It is commonly believed that a changing magnetic field *generates* a rotation of an electric field. This is not correct.

A changing magnetic field and the rotation of an electric field are equivalent expressions of the same underlying effect, namely a time dependent vector potential as in*
$${\bf \nabla} \times {\bf E} \equiv {\bf \nabla} \times {\bf A}_t \equiv  ({\bf \nabla} \times {\bf A})_t \equiv {\bf B}_t \,.$$

The origin of $${\bf \nabla} \times {\bf B} \equiv {\bf E}_t$$ is the wave equation, in its homogeneous form, $${\bf A}_{tt} = \Delta {\bf A} \,,$$ which in this form holds in the Lorenz gauge. Here indeed one could say that ${\bf A}_{tt}$ causes $\Delta {\bf A}$ and that brings the question 'How?'. All attempts to explain this have failed, among which the famous Aether theory.

You posed an excellent question!

*All uncompensated charges assumed stationary, that is $V_t=0$.

Comment: i'm trying hard but still i did not 100% understand the math you used, though i found a good yt vdo that explains the math- https://youtu.be/CbGEJrD-WMA?si=D7Z6VvSpNEcrVQTu      the only difference is that she used $\nabla^{2}A$ instead $\Delta A$ in wave eqution. So basically there exists some vector potential in space (A) where $A_{tt} \equiv E$ and $\nabla^{2}A \equiv B$. What i understood is E and B fields varying, is just result of the wave motion of this vector field A. Like waves on surface of water, water molecules going up from surface maybe equivalant to B field and water mol. moving

Comment: moving down maybe E field but they both are result of a single phenomenon i.e the wave on surface of water. I am sorry if i didnt understamd your answer but i tried hard

Comment: @AmitRai Perhaps this better than a video: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_vector_potential. Also you can find Jackson Classical Electrodynamics online.

Answer (score 2):

Towards the path of universal conservation of energy in an energetically isolated system, [Lenz (1834) formulated his law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law) as a principle avoiding self-amplification of magnetic systems: The fields of the induced currents reduce the inducing field in the same sense as the field of the induced charge density on a conducting surface reduces the inducing electric field. Last line: The squares of both electromagnetic fields represent an energy density, its integral value is conserved together with all other forms of energy in an isolated system.

Comment: I now see how important lens law is now, as it prevents explosion of energy, could you look at my comment in the 1st answer and maybe verify if its true.